# Way to mark some photos 'Favourites' in Google+?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-photos

I wish there was a way to mark some of MY photos lying across/in different Google+ albums as my favourites!

Or say, in Picasa Web Albums, I want to find a way to mark some photos (which may be present in different albums of mine), and then later move/copy all those marked photos in one album.

I already know a work around to create spare email address and then tag all those photos with that tag. This work around is not very practical. Moreover, I won't be able to view all those tagged photos together at one place with one command, will I?

Comment: It's best to limit yourself to one question per question post. As for G+ photos, are you talking about your own photos or others that people have shared?

Comment: The question is one only: How can we mark some photos (as favourite may be). It is same thing in Picasa as in G+. And I'm talking about my own photos.

Answer (score 1):

Add a hash tag to the description (e.g., #Favourite).

Then, in your Photos, just search for your hashtag and you should get your favorite photos.

Comment: I'll try and let you know. Thank you very much. Hoped there was a way to do this with multiple selected photos.